# maven-assembly-plugin and jar name conflict

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project with two dependencies (third-party libraries), and unfortunately their names and versions are same:

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>b</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Both dependencies have same `artifactId` and `version`, but different `groupId`.

I need to create a distribution package for my project. All dependencies must be copied to `lib/` folder. Here is a minimal configuration for `maven-assembly-plugin`, assembly.xml:

```
<id>package</id>
<formats>
    <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

As a result both dependencies should be copied to `lib/` inside of zip archive, but actually only one artifact is there:

```
$ find target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-package/
target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-package/
target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-package/lib
target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-package/lib/artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

As one of possible solutions, jar file name should include `groupId` - then name conflict should disappear.

So the question is: how can I configure `maven-assembly-plugin` (or some other plugin) to include both dependencies into my distribution archive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `outputFileNameMapping` in the dependency set to include the group ID:

```
<dependencySets>
   <dependencySet>
       <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
       <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.groupId}-${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
   </dependencySet>
```