# Looking for "packaging" property for Maven project

Tags: maven

Is there a property to get the packaging type (*jar*, *war*, ...) of a maven project?

I'd expect something like *project.packaging* (similar to *project.artifactId*), but it seems not available.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this property?

Comment: I want to apply a prefix to the final project name of all modules packaged as jar, via build-helper-maven-plugin configured in a parent pom. Of course, I could also directly set finalName in each jar module, but I wonder why there is no property containing the module's packaging type.

Comment: Why do you like to do this? What is the problem you are trying to solve? If I read `build-helper-maven-plugin` it sounds wrong... Apart from that the `finalName` will not work because it's only for the name in `target` directory... nothing else...

Comment: I want to avoid .jar file name conflicts, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461859/maven-assembly-plugin-and-jar-name-conflict. The names of created .war files shall be kept.